# Unable to import python module in JMeter

Tags: python, jmeter, sftp

Hi I am trying to test the performance of an sftp server using JMeter while uploading files to the server in python code.

my code to upload a file:

```
import socket
import os
import time
import threading
import paramiko

#-------
#defining the variables: host, port, user, password, serverpath, localpath, uploadDataAmount and sleepTime
#here I just define the variables it is not related to the problem. 
#I didn't add it because it contains ip and password of the server. 
#-------

transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(None, user, password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)


fileServer = sftp.open(serverpath, 'ab')
fileClient = open(localpath, 'rb')
try:
    data = fileClient.read(uploadDataAmount)
    while(data != b''):
        fileServer.write(data)
        size = str(fileServer._get_size())
        print("file size in bytes before going to sleep: "+size)
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        print("waking up ")
        data = fileClient.read(uploadDataAmount)
finally:
    fileClient.close()
    fileServer.close()

if sftp:
    sftp.close()
if transport:
    transport.close()
```

I tested my python code in visual studio and it works fine

I am new to JMeter so I am not exactly sure how it fully works, in order to make it work with python code I downloaded jython.jar file and added it to the lib directory in my JMeter directory. But my code uses the paramiko package so when I try to run it jmeter returns the error:
`Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named paramiko in <script>`

I tried to change the paramiko import to this:

```
import sys

sys.path.append(
    "C:\\Users\\YShay\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages")
from paramiko import Transport, SFTPClient
```

and again it worked fine in visual studio.

but I got the following error in jmeter:
`Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named six in <script>`

Can anyone please help me? How can I import paramiko in my python code in jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you installed this `paramiko` module into your Python and you need to **install it into Jython** in order to be able to use it with JMeter's JSR223 Sampler.

something like:

```
jython -m pip install paramiko
```

More information: [Extending Jython with pypi modules](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Extending-Jython-with-pypi-modules)

---

In general your approach is not the best, [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider switching to Groovy, you can get SSH/SFTP connectivity via [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library.

If you just need to upload the file to the server using SFTP protocol you can consider using [SSH SFTP Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-sftp) so you won't even to have to write a single line of code and bring "alien" Python into pure Java environment. Check out [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter/) article for comprehensive information